# MongoDB: $lookup on an indexed property vs $in on a non-indexed property

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I am currently using MongoDB 3.5, I have two collections (users,items). Each user has a list of items

```
//users
{
   _id: ObjectId('userObjId1')
   itemArray: [ 
      { ObjectId('itemA'), specialId: '123-this-is-unique'},
      { ObjectId('itemB'), specialId: '456-this-is-unique'},
      { ObjectId('itemC'),specialId: '789-this-is-unique'},
   ]
}
```

and items

```
//items
{
   _id: ObjectId('itemA')
   specialId: '123this-is-unique'
   owner: ObjectId('userObjId1')
}
```

One of my operations involve querying for users, given an array of `specialIds`

In my items collection, the items' `specialId`s are indexed.

**Which one would be a better practice** (and potentially better performance)?

A) Query the array of `specialIds` in the users' collection using the `$in` operator. 
Pros: query stays within the same collection
Cons: The `itemArray` itself in each user is not indexed, from my understanding this may affect the performance

B) Query in the items collection, project the `owner` and use it to run `$lookup` in the users collection
Pros: newer sytanx, since `specialIds` is already indexed in the items collection, it should be a better performance.
Cons: Needs to access two collections in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many users you have, and how many items each user has.

Plan A will work well if you have a small number of users, dozens perhaps hundreds, or if you can create an index on `{"itemArray.specialId":1}`

Plan B will use the index on `specialId` to selecting the items, and then the `_id` index in the users collection during lookup, which should perform fairly well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually would be having many users, but likely a smaller number for itemsArray. In that case I guess I should go with Plan B.